# Express Route handlers

Tags: node.js, express

hei everyone, I'm new to nodejs and express , I'm still reading the express guide , but i couldn't get the purpose of making the route handlers as an array of functions.

here is the example :

considernig these 2 functions

```js
var cb0 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB0')
  next()
}

var cb1 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB1')
  next()
}
```

what is the difference between this :

```js
app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by this function ...')
})
```

and this one ?

```js
app.get('/example/d', cb0, cb1, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by thisfunction ...')

})
```

Please, help me to understand why shall we use arrays ?

and another question, I noticed in some codes, that we pass error as an argument to the next function : next(error) , what is it for ??

thank you in advance for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally use an array to pass in multiple middleware functions, but you can use either. See the [documentation for `app.get()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method).

Regarding `next(err)` – check out [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) and look for the section titled 
"Error-handling middleware". If you call `next()` and pass in an Error object, then the function that you designated to be your error handler will run. It's a nice way to handle the control flow that you want to occur when an error is returned from a route.